# Rest framework permission for specific view

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to only authenticated user can add, create, delete... for specific views(Not all views).

Here is my settings.py

[settings.py]

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

After do this, Unexpectedly, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly permission was applied every views.

So I add this line,

`'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',`

and in views.py,

Views where do not need permission, add this line.

`permission_classes = (AllowAny,)`

It works perfectly. But I wonder that is it correct way?

I just only insert `'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',` to settings.py

But why this permission applied for every view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way of doing it, you set a default permission and view-specific permission for each view.

According to the DRF documentation, if you don't set a default permission in settings, it defaults to `AllowAny`.

[Django Rest Framework permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) has all the answers to your question

Comment: Bernard Parah Thanks! :)